# what is OQAM (Offset QAM) and why it is required?

Tags: filters, modulation, ofdm, filter-bank

Currently I am studying about a modulation technique FBMC (Filter Bank Multicarrier) which is a predecessor of OFDM. The difference with OFDM is that, FBMC does not have a CP (Cyclic Prefix) which is a better use of spectrum. On the other hand, it is susceptible to ISI (Inter Symbol Interference) due to the absence of GI (Guard Interval) when transmitted over wireless channel.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJZyn.jpg). FBMC uses prototype filters to shape the out of band emission to lower the interference.

There is a concept of FBMC-OQAM (sometimes referred as staggered multitone or SMT), where the input signal is first converted to QAM symbols and further processed into OQAM symbols[2].

Can anyone explain to me in very simple words / general context:

#. What is the purpose of OQAM (ref.2 has a figure) and how it is making the signal orthogonal?

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJZyn.jpg)https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5753092

[2]https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8255374

Comment: Can you post the figures since not everyone will be able to download the documents since many will have to pay to download?

Comment: updated with figure

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in theory and error performance there is no difference. But in practice, OQPSK  decrases the maximum phase alteriation from 180 to 90 degrees which is better for RF power amplifiers.